# Adobe DRM Activator error

Tags: adobe-reader, drm

When I try to open a particular PDF file within Adobe Reader X, it pushes it to open within Adobe Digital Editions.

However the following error is shown. Can someone please help?

```
pdffilename.pdf:
Adobe DRM Error
System:  7
State:  4
Class:  15
Code:  31
Message:  Error on response from server.
Scroll below or view error.log for more details.
Your Adobe software could not be activated.
HTTP error on Adobe DRM Activator request.
Adobe DRM Activator error.
Client Code:  31 - HTTP Code:  556
Fault location:  15
--- end ---
```

Comment: Is your firewall blocking access?

Comment: ^ or a Hosts redirection.

Comment: Hosts file is ok, Windows Firewall is turned off. All other internet/networking activity on this pc is ok.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Adobe has turned OFF the server that was issuing the relevant permissions in reguard to DRM the advice that i have read on the various forums is to get the online shop to reissue you with a new book good luck on that.